# Swift, Kingfisher Cache not working properly?

Tags: swift, image, caching, kingfisher

I am trying to cache images using the Cocoapod KingFisher, the code i am using does display the image from the database storage but it does no caching. I am curious as to know why?

The print always says "cache Result none". And i also notice that the images are not cached.

Code for calling the imageDownloader:

```
DownloadImage(imageId : nextUser.id, cardImage: secondProfilePic)
```

Code for downloading and caching, also for checking if cached.

```
func DownloadImage(imageId : String, cardImage : UIImageView){

        let imagesStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profilepic/").child(imageId)
        //Get URL For Cache
        imagesStorageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle any errors
                cardImage.image = UIImage(named: "RentOutProfilePic")
                print("Error")
            } else {
                // Get the download URL for '.jpg'
                let pathURL = url
                print("Sets Image")
                cardImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                cardImage.kf.setImage(with: pathURL,
                                                  options: [
                                                    .transition(.fade(0.3)),
                                                    .cacheOriginalImage
                    ])
            }
            if let url = url{
                let tempUrl:String = url.path
                let cache = ImageCache.default
                let cached = cache.imageCachedType(forKey: tempUrl)
                print("cache Result \(cached)")
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Would appreciate any help with this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Kingfisher is using `url.absoluteString` as the cache key for an image by default. So in your code, `url.path` will always return you the result of "not cached".
2. You are trying to print the cache result as the same time when you set the image. At the first time, your image would be in download progress so you always get `.none` even you set the key correctly according to 1. In the following invocation of this method with the same id, you should get a cache result either as disk or memory.
3. I am not sure how did you get the conclusion of "the images are not cached". Kingfisher is doing cache based on url by default. If you have different urls every time (which is returned from your `imagesStorageRef`) you call the image view setting method, there would be no matching cache and downloading would happen. If this is your case, you can customize to use the `imageId` as the cache key instead. To do that, you need to specify another cache key. See this [wiki section](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#using-another-cache-key) for more.